# Separate DLLs for MVC 3 Controllers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, dll, controller

When I am publishing my MVC 3 Razor project, it creates a single DLL file for my whole project. I need to have separate DLLs for every controller I have. So that whenever I want to change any Controller code, I would deploy only that DLL.

Comment: If all your controllers are in the same dll, when you change code for only one of the controllers, you'd still only be deploying one dll? What benefit are you getting from having all controllers in different dlls?

Comment: Why do you need to work this way?

Comment: Its a large project with lots of Views and controllers. Deploying the whole project via single DLL might be a risky option as it would affect the whole project and need to be tested completely. Why can't I publish just one file as we usually do in web forms projects. Any Help ?

Comment: Define "*risky*"? I have worked on pretty large web projects (20+ controllers) and never had to split them up into separate DLLs.

Comment: Risky means chances of errors will increase. Initial deployments wont be affected by this but when I need to change any controller 2,3 months ahead, i would prefer to deploy that single file rather deploying the whole project and affect other sequences.